# How to display two Rows, side by side in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently trying to create a progressbar and here I am creating Rows that should display side by side. For that I have put two Rows one below the other but It's display one below the other. I want it to be one next to other with little Space in between them.

Currently, it's displaying like this[image]

So, there are two Rows below the Text content, what I want is , the Row with Gray colour to be displayed on the left of the Row with white colour. I want total 4 four Rows to be displayed next to each other. Below is the code that I have written

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

@Composable
fun SpeechScreen1() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(21.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Please read the following text:",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                lineHeight = 28.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                color = Color(0xFF000000)
            )
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(9.dp))
        Text(
            text = "One morning Dorothy crossed the hall of the palace
and knocked on the door of another girl named Trot. When told to
enter, Dorothy found that Trot had company, an old sailor-man with a
wooden leg who was sitting by the open window puffing smoke from a
pipe.",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                lineHeight = 40.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(300),
                color = Color(0xFF080808)
            )
        )

        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(77.dp)
            .height(7.dp)
            .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
            .padding(top = 26.dp)) {
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(77.dp)
            .height(7.dp)
            .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
            .padding(top = 26.dp)) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just wrap those `Row`s in another `Row`. You can then use `arrangement` instead of that `Spacer`, and you can replace those hardcoded `width`s with a `weight`.

Comment: I am fairly new to jetpack compose, can you put the entire modified code. What is the difference between Spacer and Arrangement, can't we use them interchnageably ?

Comment: I could, but in my experience the best way to learn is to just try things out. Tinker with your code a bit, and next time your intuition on how to make a layout work will be better.

Comment: I created a Row and added two Rows in it. It works now

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand will the concept of **layouts** in compose, Your problem is that you are putting the `Row`s inside a `Column` which means they will be **stacked vertically on top of each other**, on that note i think you should go back to compose basics and try to really understand how a `Row` works, how `Column` works and how `Box` works because these are **the essentiel layouts you will need in every single project**.
On that note here is how you can acheive what you want using a `Row` and `Box`s to make it :

```
@Composable
fun SpeechScreen1() {

    val listOfColors = listOf(
        Color(0xFF080808),
        Color(0xFF757575),
        Color(0xFFB35353),
        Color(0xFF750E0E)
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(21.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Please read the following text:",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                lineHeight = 28.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                color = Color(0xFF000000)
            )
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(9.dp))
        Text(
            text = "One morning Dorothy crossed the hall of the palace and knocked on the door of another girl named Trot. When told to enter, Dorothy found that Trot had company, an old sailor-man with a wooden leg who was sitting by the open window puffing smoke from a pipe.",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                lineHeight = 40.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(300),
                color = Color(0xFF080808)
            )
        )

        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(8.dp)
        ) {
            repeat(4) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(listOfColors[it])
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Change your parent layout from a `Column` to a `Row`

this:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(21.dp)
    ) {
```

to this:

```
Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(21.dp)
    ) {
```

Comment: No, it's not working, the entire look changes